# Mongodb Query to merge attributes from multiple documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Merging Attributes from multiple documents in mongodb 3.4.6

I want to combine all below documents into 1 document having below attributes in the expected response .I am using mongodb 3.4.6

Note : I tried with $mergeObjects & was not compatible with the mongodb version 3.4.6. can someone suggest.

Expected :

```
{
    "_id": "76778",
    "Colour": "GREY",
"size":"Small"
    "Attr": [{
        "AttrId": 1,
        "AttrText" : "12270"
  },
  {
  "AttrId" : 2, 
  "AttrText": "12271"
    },
    {
        "AttrId": 7,
        "AttrValueId": "44"

    },
    {
        "AttrId": 8,
        "AttrDate": "2009-04-15T01:00:00Z"

    }
    ]

}
```

source documents from mongodb

Doc  1

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Product_76778", 
    "ProductDesc" : {
        "ProdNo" : "76778", 
        "Colour" : "GREY", 
"size":"Small"

    }, 
    "ProductType" : "SKU", 
    "ProdNo" : "76778", 
    "OrderLevel" : 1
}
```

Doc 2

```
{ 
    "_id" : "ProductAttr_76778_2", 
   "ProdNo" : "76778", 
    "AttrId" : 1, 
    "AttrText" : "12270",
    "OrderLevel" : 2    
}
```

Doc 3

```
{ 
    "_id" : "ProductAttr_76778_3", 
   "ProdNo" : "76778", 
    "AttrId" : 2, 
    "AttrText" : "12271", 
    "OrderLevel" : 2
}
```

Doc 4

```
{ 
    "_id" : "ProductAttr_76778_4", 
    "ProdNo" : "76778",
    "AttrId" : 7, 
    "AttrValueId" : "44", 
    "OrderLevel" : 2

}
```

Doc 5

```
{ 
    "_id" : "ProductAttr_76778_5", 
    "ProdNo" : "76778",
    AttrId" : 8, 
    "AttrDate" : "2009-04-15T01:00:00Z", 
    "OrderLevel" : 2
}
```